# Hover for SVG shapes outside of SVG element

Tags: svg

I have a weird issue in Chrome. I have a svg element with `overflow: visible`. It contains a circle. If I programmatically change the cx/cy on the circle to move it outside of the svg element, it is still displayed, *but* mouse events like hover does not seem to be registered.

The weird thing is if the circle is initially set with the same coordinates, hover works fine. The loss of hover is only if the coordinates are changed through JavaScript.

Here is a minimal example:

```
<style>

svg { overflow: visible; }

.test-dot {
    stroke: green;
    stroke-width: 10;
}

.test-dot:hover {
    stroke: red;
}

</style>
<div style="margin-top:100px;">
<svg style="border:solid black 1px;">
<circle id="test-dot" cx="20" cy="20" r="4" class="test-dot"></circle>
</svg>
</div>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('test-dot').setAttribute('cy', -20)">Move up</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('test-dot').style.cy = -20">Move up (css)</button>
```

The circle responds to hover initially, but click one of the buttons and it moves and stops responding to hover. But if cy is changed in the source rather then through JavaScript, it remains responsive to hover.

Comment: perhaps you should report this to the Chrome bugtracker (or check whether it's already been reported).